# Find the cell containing the substring and return the whole string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like shown below.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Random | Rubbish |
| Whooops it is present here | Not relevant |
| Keep looking | You will never find me |

I want to search the whole dataframe and look for any cell that contains the substring 'Whoops'. If found i want to return 'Whoops it is present here' which is the whole string which the substring is a part of. How do i achieve this in pandas? The dataframe i am working with is bigger than this but this is just an example.

Comment: `df.unstack()[df.unstack().str.contains('Whooops')]`